# Bootstrap: Class for margin-right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I believe to provide standard margin-left we can use class "Offset" in bootstrap. At the same time what is the class that can be used to provide standard margin-right?
example:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="offset2 span8"></div>
</div>
```

for some reason I need to give margin-right equivalent to offset2. Some solution will be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect it's entirely redundant. Your example shows why.

Comment: On a side note, you should use the span-x class and then your offset (ie. class="span8 offset2").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no equivalent class  to offset-x for margin-right and for good reason, it is not needed. Think of it this way, if you need a 6 column div that is offset both right and left 3 columns, you would use:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">Your content...</div>
</div>
```

Also, if you have a 6 column div that needs to only be offset 2 columns BUT, the offset should be 2 columns on the right, the code would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset4">Your content...</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind you are always working in 12 columns (unless changes in variables.less) so you can use span-x AND offset-x to achieve position desired. If you are looking to tweak additional pixels, add an additional class(or ID) to your content container inside of your span. For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset4">
        <div class="tweaked-margin">Your content...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.tweaked-margin {
    margin-right: 4px; // or whatever you need
}
```

Comment: While reading this I get another question in mind. I use to write {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;} to keep the content always position at center. If I write something like <div class="span8 offset2">My entire content</div>, whether this will be the equivalent code to keep my content always at center in responsive-fluid pages leaving equal space in both left and right side of the content? Thanks for your time spent on this. It is of great help.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. Also, no setting widths in px, think in percentages. If you do need a bit more control, use max/min-width (or heights for that matter). This is acceptable as browser support goes back to IE8. Also, if I want to center elements, say a button, rather than adding margin: 0 auto to the element itself, I usually just wrap it in a block level container and apply text-align: center; to it. Think in this way; always first set your positioning with the grid, using the span-x and offsets as needed for all primary positioning then adjust from there.

Comment: This will not work on mobile display, as after certain device width, every span converts to span12.